# How to Create a menu with JSON fetched from Webserver PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I want to make a mobile application using Cordova for my school homework project, and i need to fetch data from PHP Web Server, me already have JSON for this. 
This is the example of my mobile app map :
http://prntscr.com/fhq63c .
This is the looks of my JSON :

**Product Category :**

```
[[
{"id":1,"name":"Product 1","created_at":"2017-06-06 08:31:34","updated_at":"2017-06-06 09:16:18"},
{"id":2,"name":"Product 2","created_at":"2017-06-06 09:16:12","updated_at":"2017-06-06 09:16:12"},
{"id":3,"name":"Product 3","created_at":"2017-06-06 09:16:24","updated_at":"2017-06-06 09:16:24"}
]]
```

**Package Cateogry :**

```
[[
{"id":1,"product_id":"1","name":"Package 1-1","jumlah_user":"1","created_at":"2017-06-06 09:34:11","updated_at":"2017-06-06 09:34:11"},
{"id":2,"product_id":"1","name":"Package 1-2","jumlah_user":"1","created_at":"2017-06-06 09:35:49","updated_at":"2017-06-06 10:03:43"},
{"id":3,"product_id":"2","name":"Package 2-1","jumlah_user":"1","created_at":"2017-06-07 03:03:35","updated_at":"2017-06-07 03:03:35"},
{"id":4,"product_id":"2","name":"Package 2-2","jumlah_user":"1","created_at":"2017-06-07 03:30:11","updated_at":"2017-06-07 03:30:11"},
{"id":5,"product_id":"3","name":"Package 3-1","jumlah_user":"12","created_at":"2017-06-07 03:31:36","updated_at":"2017-06-07 03:31:36"},
]]
```

**List Price**

```
[[
{"id":1,"package_id":"1","harga":"700000.00","masa_training":"2 x 1 jam","masa_maintenance":"2 bulan","tanggal_efektif":"2018-01-01","created_at":"2017-06-07 03:45:20","updated_at":"2017-06-07 03:45:20"},
{"id":2,"package_id":"2","harga":"500000.00","masa_training":"500","masa_maintenance":"100","tanggal_efektif":"2019-01-01","created_at":"2017-06-07 03:48:23","updated_at":"2017-06-07 03:48:23"},
{"id":3,"package_id":"3","harga":"50000.00","masa_training":"10","masa_maintenance":"20","tanggal_efektif":"2017-11-30","created_at":"2017-06-08 23:11:49","updated_at":"2017-06-08 23:11:49"}
]]
```

and this is how my menu will looks :

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu">
    <p class="productid" hidden>1</p>
    <p class="productname">Product Name</p>
  </li>
  <li class="btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu">
    <p class="productid" hidden>1</p>
    <p class="productname">Product Name</p>
  </li>
  <li class="btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu">
    <p class="productid" hidden>1</p>
    <p class="productname">Product Name</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```

and each button directly go to price list that connected to the product category.

Anyone have idea and can solved mine? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have the `json` data stored in its corresponding variables, we could do like this:

```js
(function() {
  var productCategories = [
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product 1",
        "created_at": "2017-06-06 08:31:34",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-06 09:16:18"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product 2",
        "created_at": "2017-06-06 09:16:12",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-06 09:16:12"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product 3",
        "created_at": "2017-06-06 09:16:24",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-06 09:16:24"
      }
    ]
  ];
  var packageCategories = [
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "product_id": "1",
        "name": "Package 1-1",
        "jumlah_user": "1",
        "created_at": "2017-06-06 09:34:11",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-06 09:34:11"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "product_id": "1",
        "name": "Package 1-2",
        "jumlah_user": "1",
        "created_at": "2017-06-06 09:35:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-06 10:03:43"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "product_id": "2",
        "name": "Package 2-1",
        "jumlah_user": "1",
        "created_at": "2017-06-07 03:03:35",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-07 03:03:35"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "product_id": "2",
        "name": "Package 2-2",
        "jumlah_user": "1",
        "created_at": "2017-06-07 03:30:11",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-07 03:30:11"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "product_id": "3",
        "name": "Package 3-1",
        "jumlah_user": "12",
        "created_at": "2017-06-07 03:31:36",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-07 03:31:36"
      },
    ]
  ];

  var listPrice = [
    [{
        "id": 1,
        "package_id": "1",
        "harga": "700000.00",
        "masa_training": "2 x 1 jam",
        "masa_maintenance": "2 bulan",
        "tanggal_efektif": "2018-01-01",
        "created_at": "2017-06-07 03:45:20",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-07 03:45:20"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "package_id": "2",
        "harga": "500000.00",
        "masa_training": "500",
        "masa_maintenance": "100",
        "tanggal_efektif": "2019-01-01",
        "created_at": "2017-06-07 03:48:23",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-07 03:48:23"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "package_id": "3",
        "harga": "50000.00",
        "masa_training": "10",
        "masa_maintenance": "20",
        "tanggal_efektif": "2017-11-30",
        "created_at": "2017-06-08 23:11:49",
        "updated_at": "2017-06-08 23:11:49"
      }
    ]
  ];

  function buildProductCategoryMenu(productCategories) {
    var ul = "",
      i, obj, len = productCategories.length;
    ul = "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      obj = productCategories[i];
      ul += "<li class=\"btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu\">";
      ul += "<p class=\"productid\" hidden>";
      ul += obj.id;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "<p class=\"productname\">";
      ul += obj.name;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";
    return ul;
  }

  function setEventsProductCategoryMenu() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("productname"),
      i, len = elems.length,
      ele;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      ele = elems[i];
      ele.onclick = function() {
        showPackageName(this.previousSibling.innerHTML, packageCategories[0]);
      };
    }
  }

  function showPackageName(id, packageCategories) {
    var packageCategory = packageCategories.find(function(x) {
      return x.product_id === id;
    });
    if (packageCategory !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("packageName").innerHTML = "Package Name: " + packageCategory.name;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: " + showPriceBasedPackageCategory(packageCategory.id, listPrice[0]);
    }
  }

  function showPriceBasedPackageCategory(id, listPrice) {
    var obj;
    obj = listPrice.find(function(x) {
      return x.package_id === id.toString();
    });
    return (obj === undefined) ? "" : obj.harga;
  }
  document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = buildProductCategoryMenu(productCategories[0]);
  setEventsProductCategoryMenu();
})();
```

```css
#menu {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#content {
  border: solid 1px #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content">
  <p id="packageName"></p>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```

---

**With AJAX (Native JavaScript [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object):**

By using a simple json file which contains all the data getting from the server.

**JSON File:** https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/786a8e7c3f4ff1a0569013a1d4d1b8ad/raw/eb62b89d43e310997f9507be2d25f7fa375ddb6c/productCategoryPackageCategoryListPrice.json

```js
(function() {
  var newXHR = null;
  // XMLHttpRequest helper function.
  function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    newXHR.open(type, url, true);
    newXHR.send(data);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response);
      }
    };
  }

  function buildProductCategoryMenu(productCategories) {
    var ul = "",
      i, obj, len = productCategories.length;
    ul = "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      obj = productCategories[i];
      ul += "<li class=\"btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu\">";
      ul += "<p class=\"productid\" hidden>";
      ul += obj.id;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "<p class=\"productname\">";
      ul += obj.name;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";
    return ul;
  }

  function setEventsProductCategoryMenu(packageCategories, listPrice) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("productname"),
      i, len = elems.length,
      ele;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      ele = elems[i];
      ele.onclick = function() {
        showPackageName(this.previousSibling.innerHTML, packageCategories, listPrice);
      };
    }
  }

  function showPackageName(id, packageCategories, listPrice) {
    var packageCategory = packageCategories.find(function(x) {
      return x.product_id === id;
    });
    if (packageCategory !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("packageName").innerHTML = "Package Name: " + packageCategory.name;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: " + showPriceBasedPackageCategory(packageCategory.id, listPrice);
    }
  }

  function showPriceBasedPackageCategory(id, listPrice) {
    var obj;
    obj = listPrice.find(function(x) {
      return x.package_id === id.toString();
    });
    return (obj === undefined) ? "" : obj.harga;
  }

  sendXHR("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/786a8e7c3f4ff1a0569013a1d4d1b8ad/raw/eb62b89d43e310997f9507be2d25f7fa375ddb6c/productCategoryPackageCategoryListPrice.json", null, function(response) {
    if (response !== null && response.length > 0) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = buildProductCategoryMenu(jsonResponse.data.productCategories[0]);
      setEventsProductCategoryMenu(jsonResponse.data.packageCategories[0], jsonResponse.data.listPrice[0]);
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
#menu {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#content {
  border: solid 1px #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content">
  <p id="packageName"></p>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```

---

By using three json files which contains its corresponding data getting from the server.

**JSON Files:**

- Product Categories: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/3e2689ac7197d69a9624b32d5600e150/raw/18e36651acb9b9883732081a18c7deae7388eb0f/productCategories.json.
- Package Categories: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/5d0caaffd3e22506fe1311eb4e31b7cc/raw/09a305b83cb725907d8ee9c24d487bdd85591b14/packageCategories.json.
- List Price: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/cd73c2caf8d53ff1f453eafc14046357/raw/c943af91e7dd3e5e14e5763d8a2a14f649ddd810/listPrice.json.

```js
(function() {
  var newXHR = null;
  // XMLHttpRequest helper function.
  function sendXHR(type, url, data, callback) {
    newXHR = new XMLHttpRequest() || new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    newXHR.open(type, url, true);
    newXHR.send(data);
    newXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState === 4) {
        callback(this.response);
      }
    };
  }

  function buildProductCategoryMenu(productCategories) {
    var ul = "",
      i, obj, len = productCategories.length;
    ul = "<ul class=\"list-group\">";
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      obj = productCategories[i];
      ul += "<li class=\"btn btn-lg btn-default list-group-item btn-menu\">";
      ul += "<p class=\"productid\" hidden>";
      ul += obj.id;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "<p class=\"productname\">";
      ul += obj.name;
      ul += "</p>";
      ul += "</li>";
    }
    ul += "</ul>";
    return ul;
  }

  function setEventsProductCategoryMenu(packageCategories, listPrice) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("productname"),
      i, len = elems.length,
      ele;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      ele = elems[i];
      ele.onclick = function() {
        showPackageName(this.previousSibling.innerHTML, packageCategories, listPrice);
      };
    }
  }

  function showPackageName(id, packageCategories, listPrice) {
    var packageCategory = packageCategories.find(function(x) {
      return x.product_id === id;
    });
    if (packageCategory !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("packageName").innerHTML = "Package Name: " + packageCategory.name;
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: " + showPriceBasedPackageCategory(packageCategory.id, listPrice);
    }
  }

  function showPriceBasedPackageCategory(id, listPrice) {
    var obj;
    obj = listPrice.find(function(x) {
      return x.package_id === id.toString();
    });
    return (obj === undefined) ? "" : obj.harga;
  }

  sendXHR("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/3e2689ac7197d69a9624b32d5600e150/raw/18e36651acb9b9883732081a18c7deae7388eb0f/productCategories.json", null, function(response) {
    if (response !== null && response.length > 0) {
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
      document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = buildProductCategoryMenu(jsonResponse.productCategories[0]);

      sendXHR("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/5d0caaffd3e22506fe1311eb4e31b7cc/raw/09a305b83cb725907d8ee9c24d487bdd85591b14/packageCategories.json", null, function(response) {
        if (response !== null && response.length > 0) {
          jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
          var packageCategories = jsonResponse.packageCategories;

          sendXHR("GET", "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dannyjhonston/cd73c2caf8d53ff1f453eafc14046357/raw/c943af91e7dd3e5e14e5763d8a2a14f649ddd810/listPrice.json", null, function(response) {
            if (response !== null && response.length > 0) {
              jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
              var listPrice = jsonResponse.listPrice;
              setEventsProductCategoryMenu(packageCategories[0], listPrice[0]);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
#menu {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#content {
  border: solid 1px #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="content">
  <p id="packageName"></p>
  <p id="price"></p>
</div>
```

[image: AccesControl Allow Origin: *]

Comment: @ danny fardy jhonston bermudez Do you have the one with ajax ? because i think i doesnt need to rewrite the json in the script

Comment: @vl14b I've updated my answer. If you need more detailed explanation, let me know.

Comment: i already tried it and try to change the github(your json) link to link where i store my json, but why "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" appear out of nowhere?

Comment: Because your link needs to have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in the response headers. See my update.

Comment: well, now i got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at index.html:156
    at XMLHttpRequest.newXHR.onreadystatechange (index.html:99)
(anonymous) @ index.html:156
newXHR.onreadystatechange @ index.html:99`

Comment: this is line 156 : `document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = buildProductCategoryMenu(jsonResponse.productCategories[0]);`

and this is line 99 : `callback(this.response);`

Comment: Hmm, i never write in jsfiddle i hope this is ok : https://jsfiddle.net/ah0gn4ay/ ,  btw can we discuss outside stackoverflow ? thanks

Comment: Your links has differents properties in the json. I've made a demo with some changes in my demo site. http://dfjb.webcindario.com/demo.html. The code will display the data when the properties in your json exist or match.

Comment: Erm, yes, i translated my json when i post in this stack , and change it after it because i realized something. So the code is work !  But, sorry if i can ask again, can we make it open a new page instead a dropdown ? Thanks

Comment: Oh and btw, why its just appear like this : http://prntscr.com/fm8x3h when in my json i have more than one data with the same produk_id ? (like this : http://prntscr.com/fm8x6y)

Comment: In the code that we have `Array.find()` returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

And yeah, I can help you through Skype: **djhonston**.